# bash -c running script in the same process

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I ran some tests to see how `bash -c` spawns subprocesses for the command given to it, and noticed some strange behavior.

This is the content of `test.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env fish
echo $fish_pid
readlink /proc/$fish_pid/exe
```

Here are the experiment results:

```
$ bash -c 'echo $$ && ./test.sh'
296
296
/usr/bin/fish

$ bash -c 'echo $$ && ./test.sh && echo $$'
403
404
/usr/bin/fish
403

$ bash -c 'echo $$; ./test.sh'
317
318
/usr/bin/fish

$ bash -c 'echo $$; exec ./test.sh'
349
349
/usr/bin/fish
```

It's almost as if bash is doing tail call optimization by automatically inserting an `exec` in the first case. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what you are describing; Bash notices that it can reuse the current process, and so avoids doing a `fork()` system call and then wait for the subprocess when just an `exec()` system call is sufficient.

It's not clear why it's not doing that in the third case; that one would seem as clear-cut as the first one, if not even more so.